# Can I generate cucumbur html report in cypress?

Tags: cucumber, ui-automation, cypress

I set up a cypress solution with cucumber in order to use gherkin syntax to create my scenarios. But I still have an open question. Can I generate a cucumber html report like in the image bellow?
If yes, it would be great full for me if somebody can provide me an example. At the moment I use mocha reporter, but I can't see the steps for each scenario into the report, only the scenario name.

[image]

This is the actual report using mocha reporter: =>
[image]

Comment: Try this method, it will work 100%, https://softans.com/using-mochawesome-reporter-with-cypress/

Answer (score 2):

You should generate cucumber-json report.
In your package.json set configuration :

```
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
"nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
"stepDefinitions": "cypress/stepDefinitions",
"cucumberJson": {
  "generate": true,
  "outputFolder": "cypress/cucumber-json",
  "filePrefix": "",
  "fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
}
```

}

Use [html-cucumber-reporter](https://github.com/gkushang/cucumber-html-reporter) .

```
npm install cucumber-html-reporter --save-dev
```

and create js file to generate reporte :

```
const reporter = require('cucumber-html-reporter');

const options = {
  theme: 'hierarchy',
  jsonDir: 'cypress/cucumber-json',
  output: 'reports/html_simple/cucumber_report.html',
  reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
  scenarioTimestamp: true,
  launchReport: true,
  ignoreBadJsonFile: true,
  scenarioTimestamp: true,
  metadata: {
    "App Version": "1.0.0",
    "Test Environment": "STAGING",
    "Browser": "Chrome  54.0.2840.98",
    "Platform": "Windows 10",
    "Parallel": "Scenarios",
    "Executed": "Remote"
  }
};

reporter.generate(options);
```

Run your tests and execute reporter file :

```
node ./support/cucumber-html-reporter.js
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Franck Rousseau, thank you for you very helpfull answer. Now I managed to generate the cucumber-json, but I still have a problem when I execute my reporter file.

Comment: I mananged to do it.Thanks a lot. Currently I am working on attaching screenshot on the failed step fo a scenario. Many thanks Franck

Comment: Hi Sebastian,
to attach screenshot on the failed step, i used this [fix][1] and adapted for me.
In particular the screenshotsDir variable, because i use a subfolder for my features.
[1]: https://github.com/webnexusmobile/cypress-cucumber-getting-started/blob/master/cypress/reporting/report.js

Comment: Hi Franck, Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Sebastian Hi, did you figure out how to attach screenshot with failed test step?

Comment: When I try to generate above report on `Azure develops pipeline ` , it throws an error `Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'cypress/cucumber-json/cucumber_report.html.json'`.
Any Idea?